# multiple Conditionnal redirect when user fill a form

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to redirect user to different pages depending of what he filled in a input field.

example :

- when he types 1 or 2 he will be redirect to google
- when he types 3 or 4 he will be redirect to facebook
- when he types 5 he will be redirect to stackoverflow

else show a message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is unfortunately off-topic as it is written now. You need to include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `if else` statement and `window.location.href` to guide the user to the destination window.

```js
function redirect() {
  const inputVal = Number(document.getElementById("inputVal").value);
  let url = "";
  if (inputVal) {
    if (inputVal === 1 || inputVal === 2){ 
      url = "https://www.google.com"
    } else if (inputVal === 3 || inputVal === 4){ 
      url = "https://www.facebook.com"
    } else {
      console.log('Redirect Not Defined!!')
    }
  }
  
  if (url) {
    window.location.href = url
  }
}

document.getElementById("redirectButton").addEventListener("click", redirect);
```

```html
<input type="number" value=1 id="inputVal" />
<button type="button" id="redirectButton"> Redirect </button>
```

Comment: okay!! [ --fixed ]

Comment: Same as hopefully you don't use inline `style`, stop using unsafe inline `on*` handlers. Use `addEventListener()` instead. JS and CSS should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file.

Comment: If not inside a `form` try always to use `type="button"` for your `button` Elements since inherently by default the type is `"submit"`.

Comment: thanks!! have tried to improve the approach according to your inputs

Comment: Nicely done Rishu!

Answer (score 0):

I normally do not recommend the switch statement, but here it is apt

Note that here at SO the action may be blocked

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  let loc = "";
  switch (+document.getElementById("inputVal").value) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
      loc = "https://www.google.com";
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      loc = "https://www.facebook.com"
      break;
    case 5:
      loc = "https://stackoverflow.com";
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Redirect Not Defined!!')
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
  }
  if (loc) this.action = loc;
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm" target="_blank">
  <input type="number" value=1 id="inputVal" />
  <button type="submit"> Redirect </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another viable suggestion using an object as a *map* referencing desired locations by index:

```js
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

const navigate = () => {

  const addr = [
    "google.com",
    "facebook.com",
    "stackoverflow.com",
  ];

  const maps = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 1,
    4: 1,
    5: 2,
  };

  const EL_num = EL("#num");
  const url = addr[maps[EL_num.value]];

  if (url) return location.assign(`https://${url}`);
  console.log("Coudn't navigate");
};

EL("#go").addEventListener("click", navigate);
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" value="1">
<button id="go" type="button">Go</button>
```

much more clean than by using `if` or `switch` statements.

Comment: thank you. it seems working.
but how could i print a msg in page when number is wrong or don't exist

Comment: i solve it . 
by replacing conole.log line by this :
      alert("the number " + inputVal + " is incorrect !")

Comment: @CMMSAGHIR `alert` and `prompt` should  not be used any more in 2021. Rather, just print the message into a predefined element on the page.